# xpath udf (Hive) returns all the array elements , I would like to view each array element in sepearate row rather than one single row

Tags: hadoop, xpath, hive, xml-parsing

This method returns me all the @type instances in a single row as an array rather i would like to view them in separate rows.

'''xpath (columnName, '/a/b/c/d/e/@type') as Alias_name'''

Please look at the attached picture for the current result and the result which i am expecting.[Rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdlDg.png)

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LATERAL VIEW explode(array-col-name)` and follow this [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView) for more details on how to use with examples